# Sorting in primefaces datatable not working

Tags: jsf, jakarta-ee, primefaces

I use sorting in primefaces datatable and it's does not work with paginator. Where I made ​​a mistake?

```
<p:column headerText="Year" sortBy="#{questionnaireListBean.getQuestionnaireData(questionnaire, 'YEAR')}">
    #{questionnaireListBean.getQuestionnaireData(questionnaire, 'YEAR')}
</p:column>
```

And view scoped bean with init data in @PostConstruct method:

```
public String getQuestionnaireData(Questionnaire questionnaire, String column) {
    return questionnairesData.get(questionnaire).get(column);
}
```

Comment: Which primefaces version are you using ?

Comment: Plus : how is questionnaire set in the JSF page ? Is there any exception or type error indicated ?

Comment: Primefaces 3.5. When i try to remove paginator sorting is work correctly. With paginator does not work, without exceptions.

Comment: Well, pagination and sorting are working along fine here http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/datatableComplex.jsf

Comment: I try to do how it implement in example and yes, it works correctly. Problem was in 'lazy' parameter... So, is sorting works with lazy data table?

Comment: So you do have a `lazy="true"` in your datatable ?

Comment: Yes, and with lazy="true" sorting doesn't work.

Comment: dmitri, if you can post some code of the solution, that would be great.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So the true title of your question is : ***"Sorting and pagination not working together in lazy loading datatable, primefaces"***, that's more of a precise description of your problem.

As for the issue, it apprears that you should expect the problem. In [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2887248/jsf-datatable-lazy-load-filter-and-sorting), the question was *"Is there any datatable JSF component than can perform lazy load pagination, and filtering and sorting on server side. If I need to implement my own solution thanks to the teams that made client side sorting and filtering, they are useless"*, to which the answer came *"No, there isn't. Because the component library cannot know what will be the persistence mechanism."*. Of course that dated from 2010...

Taking a look into [Primefaces user guide 3.5](http://www.primefaces.org/documentation.html), it apprears that **sorting/paginator/lazy loading** can cohabit, but that's more elaborte then just adding `sortBy` to your columns.
In fact, checking page 144 of the guide, you can see that you need to :

- have a `LazyDataModel` object in your bean ;
- Override the `load` method of this object ;
- Bind the value of your datatable to this model.

Doing this, you might have sorting along with lazy loading. Haven't tried it, but this seems to adress your issue.

Best of luck.

Comment: Please do not forget to post some feedback of how you solved the problem or your progress in general, that's what the community is here for : having some trace for the futur users :) (plus, I am interested lol). Good luck !